# Restrict client requests based on origin via Rack-CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, cross-domain, cors

I have a Rails 4 API that checks for an access token during a client request. I have the [rack-cors gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) enabled and the following setup:

config/application.rb:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

I have a model called ApiApp that stores the access token. There is a concern that opening the app to any origin poses a security risk. Is there a way to store the desired Origin, for example "test.com", in ApiApp and be able to check via the rack-cors setup that it is a match on each request?

app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApiController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json
      before_filter :restrict_access

      private

      def restrict_access
        api_app = ApiApp.find_by_access_token(params[:access_token])
        # need to check that the origin is whitelisted via rack-cors
        head :unauthorized unless api_app
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm concerned that the rack-cors config loads once and is not able to access the ApiApp data.

Example request:

```
https://hello.com/api/v1/products?access_token=7b9f3cddd3914a6f45fa692997fe6dc9
```

Thanks for any thoughts. I'd appreciate being pointed to examples that show origin checking with rack-cors, alternate ways to check (perhaps header) or any arguments that this is all not necessary.